# Infragistics igListView

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui

I am configuring an infragistics igListView programmatically binding them to a json object. I want to bind an event handler when an item on the list is clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This api referanced you. You can find some samples

http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2014.2/